# installing self-signed certificate Linux yocto

Tags: linux, ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, yocto

i have a self signed certificate i generated earlier.
i installed it on my Ubuntu machine successfully.
what i did is:

```
$ cp mycert.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
$ update-ca-certificates
```

However, on my yocto machine:

```
$ cp mycert.crt /usr/share/ca-certificates
$ update-ca-certificates
```

and the result is:

```
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs... 0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d....done.
```

the cert was not installed... what can be the problem? 
thanks

Answer (score 2):

the solution:

I had to create a directory `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` and just put the certificate over there